# Can you connect to ASP.net soap service using Kerberos authentication using MonoTouch?

Tags: ios, web-services, xamarin.ios, kerberos, wse

I am trying to connect to an ASP.net soap service using Kerberos authentication using MonoTouch but it does not support WSE extensions. it returns a 401 auth failure.

Was planning on doing something like this
http://www.15seconds.com/issue/040603.htm

Is there a way to use WebServicesClientProtocol class in MonoTouch or any alternative way to do Kerberos authentication using MT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mono itself does **not** support Kerberos and all the web services code of MonoTouch is based on it.

FWIW Web Service Enhancement is very old and was never supported (2.0) by Mono. You should look at WCF and the (Silverlight-based) subset that MonoTouch support.

Comment: Is Kerberos even supported for iOS?

Comment: In general Mono provides managed implementations of what it needs to use, e.g. SSL/TLS, NTLM, XMLDSIG..., so it will work on any platform that Mono is being ported on. I did have a quick look, a long time ago...

Comment: Thanks poupou. Will try WCF with Mono. I was not sure it supports Kerberos authentication.

Comment: @SoftwareWeaver just to be 100% clear: Mono does **not** support Kerberos. My answer to competent_tech was that MonoTouch **could** support things that iOS does not support (if Mono has a managed implementation for it) - but that's not the case for Kerberos.

Comment: Sorry pouppu. I misread your post. How would you suggest supporting Kerberos auth in a MonoTouch app that has to talk to ASP.NET web service?

Comment: You'll need to find a native **GSSAPI** library and bind it (if no .NET bindings are available). A quick goggling did not turn out anything :-( but please keep us posted if you find anything